# Saving an image from PIL results in image which is totally different from the original

Tags: python, keras, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network, steganography

I'm trying to hide text inside an image and using PIL to save the encoded image from the neural network with embeds the data into the image. 
https://futureboy.us/stegano/compinput.html
I'm using this site to compare difference between the original image and the one which is encoded.
When I used opencv2 to save the image and compared the output on the website I mentioned it shows very less difference but when I used PIL to save the image it results in image which is very dim and comparing the original image and output shows all the pixel values have been changed.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.losses import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import *
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img, array_to_img
import cv2
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from PIL import Image

def rand_img(size):
    return np.random.randint(0, 256, size) / 255.0


def rand_sentence(len, max):
    return np.random.randint(0, max, len)


def onehot(sentece, max):
    onehot = np.zeros((len(sentece), max))
    for i, v in enumerate(sentece):
        onehot[i, v] = 1
    return onehot


def data_generator(image_size, sentence_len, sentence_max_word, batch_size=32):
    while True:
        x_img = np.zeros((batch_size, image_size[0], image_size[1], image_size[2]))
        x_sen = np.zeros((batch_size, sentence_len))
        y_img = np.zeros((batch_size, image_size[0], image_size[1], image_size[2]))
        y_sen = np.zeros((batch_size, sentence_len, sentence_max_word))
        for i in range(batch_size):
            img = rand_img(image_size)
            sentence = rand_sentence(sentence_len, sentence_max_word)
            sentence_onehot = onehot(sentence, sentence_max_word)
            x_img[i] = img
            x_sen[i] = sentence
            y_img[i] = img
            y_sen[i] = sentence_onehot
        yield [x_img, x_sen], [y_img, y_sen]


def get_model(image_shape, sentence_len, max_word):
    input_img = Input(image_shape)
    input_sen = Input((sentence_len,))
    embed_sen = Embedding(max_word, 100)(input_sen)
    flat_emb_sen = Flatten()(embed_sen)
    flat_emb_sen = Reshape((image_shape[0], image_shape[1], 1))(flat_emb_sen)
    trans_input_img = Conv2D(20, 1, activation="relu")(input_img)
    enc_input = Concatenate(axis=-1)([flat_emb_sen, trans_input_img])
    out_img = Conv2D(3, 1, activation='relu', name='image_reconstruction')(enc_input)
    decoder_model = Sequential(name="sentence_reconstruction")
    decoder_model.add(Conv2D(1, 1, input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))
    decoder_model.add(Reshape((sentence_len, 100)))
    decoder_model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(max_word, activation="softmax")))
    out_sen = decoder_model(out_img)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_img, input_sen], outputs=[out_img,out_sen])
    model.compile('adam', loss=[mean_absolute_error, categorical_crossentropy],
                  metrics={'sentence_reconstruction': categorical_accuracy})
    encoder_model = Model(inputs=[input_img, input_sen], outputs=[out_img])
    #return model, encoder_model, decoder_model
    return model, encoder_model, decoder_model


def ascii_encode(message, sentence_len):
    sen = np.zeros((1, sentence_len))
    for i, a in enumerate(message.encode("ascii")):
        sen[0, i] = a
    return sen


def ascii_decode(message):
    return ''.join(chr(int(a)) for a in message[0].argmax(-1))


def main():
    image_shape = (100, 100, 3)
    sentence_len = 100
    max_word = 256
    gen = data_generator(image_shape, sentence_len, max_word, 64)
    model, encoder, decoder = get_model(image_shape, sentence_len, max_word)
    try:
        model.load_weights("best_weights.h5")
    except:
        model.fit(gen, epochs=512, steps_per_epoch=400, callbacks=[
            ModelCheckpoint("best_weights.h5",monitor="loss",verbose=1,save_weights_only=True,save_best_only=True)])
    print(model.summary())
    img = np.expand_dims(img_to_array(load_img("img.jpg")) / 255.0, axis=0)
    x = input("Enter sentence:\n")
    sen = ascii_encode(x, sentence_len)
    y = encoder.predict([img, sen])
    x = np.reshape(y,(100,100,3))
    #img = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = x
    '''out = array_to_img(x)
    out.save("out.jp2")'''
    cv2.imshow("img",img)
    #rescaled = (255.0 / img.max() * (img - img.min())).astype(np.uint8)
    rescaled = (img/img.max()*255).astype(np.uint8)
    im = Image.fromarray(rescaled)
    im.save('out.png')
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    y = np.expand_dims(img_to_array(load_img("out.png")) / 255.0, axis=0)
    y_hat = decoder.predict(y)
    print(ascii_decode(y_hat))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You didn't include your input and output images, nor did you show your `import` statements nor how you opened the image.

Comment: To be clear, you saved the image with opencv with `cv2.imwrite('out.png', rescaled)`?

Comment: @Reti43 no im.save(rescaled)

Comment: @Mark_Setchell, image is an output from a cnn of type float32, and I'm trying to save it as out.png.

Comment: You said when you saved it with opencv it seemed fine. So I'm asking how you saved it there so I can compare to PIL and why it's giving you such a different output. But opencv has nothing remotely close to `im.save`, so what gives?

Comment: Here Y is an output from a neural network, while using ```cv2.imwrite("img.png",img*255.0)```
Images turns to be fine but when using the code I
```img = rescaled = (255.0 / img.max() * (img - img.min())).astype(np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray(rescaled)
im.save('out.png')```
This stores the image differently, image turns a lot less bright but when I read the image it gives the proper output when I pass it to decoder.
I'm uploading the whole code so you can understand it better.